# How to feed data to div tag while code from behind runs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looping through some records pulled from a DB, as I go through each iteration I would like to display them on a div tag on the client side one by one, I don't want to display them all at once at the end. Is this possible?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried pagination where you get let's say the first 20 records then fetch the rest. You would have to create an endpoint with pagination parameters that queries the records and then use `Javascript` to do the fetching on client side page-by-page

Comment: Can you show some code? Or what you have tried?